# Kotlin dataset javascript

Tags: java, javascript, kotlin

Tengo un boton HTML con un data attribute:

```
<button data-shop-listing='{"name": "Towel", "description": "Sunny days and warm weather - you clearly need it after a refreshing jump into the cool sea.", "price": 10.00}'>Add to cart</button>
```

Quiero acceder al data cuando se haga click en el boton usando Kotlin. Cuando se dispara el evento click hago esto, donde item es el elemento HTML que ha disparado el evento.

```
fun addItemToCart (item:EventTarget?) {
  console.log(item.dataset.shopListing)
}
```

Sin embargo el compilador da este error:"unresolved reference dataset".

Estos son mis imports:

```
import org.w3c.dom.*
import org.w3c.dom.events.*
import kotlin.browser.*
```

Comment: Las preguntas deben ir en castellano.

Comment: No me dí cuenta que escribía sólo a la comunidad castellana y no la global

Answer (score 0):

Me respondo a mi mismo:

```
fun addItemToCart (item:EventTarget?) {
val it = item as HTMLElement
  console.log(it.dataset.get("shopListing"))
}
```

El attributo data set es un metodo del tipo HTMLElement, así que hay que transformar el tipo EventTarget a este tipo. Hecho esto, hay que acceder a los metodos nativos del DOMStringMap que es el que usa el dataset https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMStringMap

Comment: Hola, eloo bienvenido. Me alegra que encontraras solucion pero dos cosas: 1 . las preguntas no pueden estar en ingles, has de traducirla o se cerrará. 2. las auto respuestas son bien recibidas pero tienes que redactarlo tal y como haria alguien que no es el autor. Explicando qué falla, y como funciona tu solucion. Un saludo